# which end follows in succession: -3,-5,-18,-21

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I am blocked, I could not find the term that follows or the recursion of the succession

$$-3,-5,-18,-21$$

I need this to find the recursion of a series of powers

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

The sequence possibly is [A039584](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C5%2C18%2C21&language=english&go=Search), i.e.,
$$
-3,-5,-18,-21,-23,-30,-33,\ldots 
$$